# Is there any template circuit converting PWM input to DC output?

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, pwm

I need to design a circuit. The inputs are a PWM siginal from a MCU and a 12V DC The output is a variable 0~12V DC. I did some inverse engineering with multimeter to some similar PCB avaliable for me. The first stage is two BJT and a MOSFET to amplify the PWM power. The second stage is something similar to a inverter, which consists of several resistors, capacitors, and inductors. I checked with oscilloscope, and it converts amplified PWM to 0~12V DC.

But, the problem is, I am not very confident with my inverse engineering. So, it would be very helpful if I can have some template circuit for such purpose, and begin with it. If anyone can share some cirtuit for this perpuse, or direct me , I would appreciate very much. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered a low pass filter?

Comment: If the output is simply a voltage _signal_ and you don't care about the current or power loss, you can use an RC low pass filter (or multiple). If the output _power_ is important, an LC filter may work, _however_, if the load is not fixed, the "Q" of the filter is not fixed, and it may "ring" or "peak". Also, LC filters tend to be much bulkier than lossy RC filters. So, is output _power_ important? Or just voltage level? Can you amplify _after_ you remove the PWM? Or do you need to amplify the PWM for efficiency?

Comment: The output is not a voltage siginal. The output power is important. It provides power to drive another cirtuit. And, the load is fixed. What is "ring" or "peak" may I ask? Technically I can amplify after removing PWM, but lost the ability of adjusting DC output. So, technically yes, but I lost the function I want to achieve, adjust DC output.

Comment: At the end it turns out being a normal usage of a LC low pass filter. Just because I lack of experience, the two nodes of a L is easily measured as the same node because a L is an open circuit at two sides. After clarify this mistake, the LC circuit is normal. Thank you very much.